# How can I change the standard files in nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, filesystem, files, filemanager

I don't like the standard files in Nautilus (the ordering by data types - Images, Music, Videos, Documents etc.), how can I change this or can I change this ordering without getting problems with several software or Ubuntu one?

Comment: so what would you like to change?

Comment: I'd like "notices, texts, tutorials, mindmaps, screenshots" instead of "music, videos, images, documents"

Answer (score 0):

You might use `xdg-user-dirs` to set up user directories.
http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs

Your directories are stored in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

xdg-user-dirs man page is readable at http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/1/xdg-user-dir/